# Pencil P of quartics surface

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, at.algebraic-topology

I'm reading an article of mumford and I want to know what it means or where I can find: the pencil has no fixed components, and the pencil is fixed components.

Thanks

Comment: Hi, Nicolas and welcome to MO. I would recommend adding a more exact reference to the article, there are several Mumfords who have published in mathematics and they all have several published articles.

Comment: @Rami: I guess that "mumford" should be the most unsignificant of all Mumfords.

Comment: the article is Further pathologies in algebraic geometry, is the second exemple about the chacarteristic map.
thanks

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you are familiar with the notion of linear system of divisors, a pencil is a linear system of (projective) dimension $1$. One says that a pencil (or an arbitrary linear system) on a variety $X$ has a fixed component $D$, where $D$ is, say, an effective Cartier divisor (if $X$ is smooth, you may repace "effective Cartier divisor" by "irreducible subvariety of codimension one") if all the divisors of the linear system in question contain $D$.

The basic definitions concerning linear systems may be found in almost any textbook (Hartshorne will do).

Comment: Thanks Serge,
Yes, I am familiar with the notion of linear system and cartier divisor.
